# Probability of being in a random interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider an Erlang$(n,\lambda)$-distributed random variable $A$ and another Erlang$(1,1)$-distributed random variable $B$ (hence exponential(1)) such that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

How to compute $P(A<t<A+B)$? 
Are the events $\{A<t\}$ and $\{t<A+B\}$ independent?

Comment: For any $t\gt 0$, the events $\{A<t\}$ and $\{t<A+B\}$ are not independent, and their complements are mutually exclusive

Comment: Could you give me a hint then how to compute $P(t<A+B\mid A<t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $t\ge 0$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(t\in [A,A+B])&=\int_0^\infty \mathsf{P}(t\in [A,A+b])\,e^{-b}\,db \\
&=\int_0^\infty \left(\int_{(t-b)\vee 0}^t \frac{\lambda^n a^{n-1}e^{-\lambda a}}{(n-1)!}\,da\right)e^{-b}\,db.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much!